# Why is my responsive navbar dropdown not working properly?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Here is HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" ng-click="navbarShow = !navbarShow">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

   <div class="navbar-collapse" collapse="!navbarShow">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ng-click="navbarShow = false">Sites<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer pull-left pull-left"></i></a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="navbarShow = false">Models<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower pull-left"></i></a></li>            
     </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Here is [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/F9OzHcawjXJmMg1KKvbd?p=preview)

When I click on the menu button the menu is popup or collapsed according to  `navbarShow` value (true or false)  and it's works fine!

But I want also collapse menu when `Sites` or `Models` clicked 
for this reason I use this row:

```
ng-click="navbarShow = false"
```

inside each item (Sites and Models).

But when I click on `Sites` or `Models` the menu is not collapsed.

Why is it collapsed when I click on `Sites` or `Models`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [doc of bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse), to controle the collapse element, it's not `collapse` attribute. But the `data-target` and the `data-toggle` attributes:

> You can use a link with the href attribute, or a button with the data-target attribute. In both cases, the data-toggle="collapse" is required.

Please see this modifyed [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FCrS54cQsW5SoWn6efM5?p=preview) which works.